# Recognize files depending on extension

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

i need to recognize files with different extensions even when there is a combination of multiple extensions
so if my cwd has this files:

```
file-1 .zip
file-2 .tar
file-3 .tar.gz
file-4 .gz
file-5 .zip.tar
file-6 .tar.gz
file-7 .gz
```

i need to tell bash what to do when the extension (in this case) is:

- zip
- tar
- zip.tar
- tar.gz
- gz

because for every extension i need to do different things, this implies that if the extension is .tar (only) or .gz (only) i need to do certain things, but if the extension is .tar.gz i need to run another snippet.

example:
if the filename has .tar extension i need to do

```
# stuff
tar xf filename.tar
# other stuff
```

if the filename has .zip.tar extension i need to run more complex code (but the code is not totally dependent on the extensions, my only objective is to get the full extension of the filename (filename.tar.gz should return .tar.gz instead of .gz or .tar)

Also, is there any way using gawk?

Comment: `case "${filename##*.}" in`... will give the extension, within the `gz` case, just do it a second time and test for `.tar`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 3):

Use `case`:

```
case "$filename" in 
    *.tar.gz) code for .tar.gz ;;
    *.gz) code for .gz ;;
    *.zip.tar) code for .zip.tar ;;
    *.tar) code for .tar ;;
    ...
esac
```

Just make sure you put the combined extensions before the single extensions that they contain, because `case` executes the statements for the first pattern that matches.

Answer (score 0):

The `file` command is a good option to detect file types, then you can write a logic

```
file -i test.*

test.gz:     application/x-gzip; charset=binary
test.tar:    application/x-tar; charset=binary
test.tar.gz: application/x-gzip; charset=binary
test.zip:    application/zip; charset=binary
```

Comment: to use if extension is not enough specific

Comment: @kyodev Linux does not rely on extensions like Window$, remove the extension and run the command and you'll get the same result.

Comment: Yes of course.Just for information. Parse $( file ) is slower than to do directly on a string (ex: 9130 ms/5722 ms)